# How to set image in ImageView from BASE64 string reciveb dy JSON

Tags: java, android, arrays, imageview, base64

I have something like:

```
JSONArray Icons      = new JSONArray();
```

In AsyncTask I'm reciving images in **BASE64** from Flask server:

```
Icons      = (JSONArray) result.get("Icons");
```

Now I need to update ImageView with images that are stored in JSONArray in BASE64. It should be something like:

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(Icons.get(i)...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decode the `base64` image and set in imageView like this:

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(strBase64, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length); 
image.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
```

Also, check whether you're receiving a valid base64 string before setting it.